# Can we add a migration path to stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, migration

Programming questions are off topic here. Yet programming questions get asked. I would like to be able to migrate them to SO where they might get answered. At the moment when I flag something off topic, I can only indicate that it belongs on meta.wp.se.com. I know each site has its own migration target and would like SO added to ours.

Answer (score 8):

Migration paths are only set up on graduated sites. So when Windows Phone graduates, we'll set some up.

Till then, flag questions that should be migrated for moderator attention and your friendly neighbourhood diamonds should help you out. :)

Answer (score 3):

The moderators of this site are able to migrate to any other stack exchange site. I am not 100% sure, but you might see this option once you get enough rep.

Comment: It's not a matter of rep.  Beta sites do not get migration options for normal users.  What you should do in the meantime is VtC as off-topic, and flag it for the moderators with a note suggesting migration.